# Python, Django, DataTables Invalid JSON

Tags: jquery, python, json, django, datatable

I have hit a road block in learning Django.  :-)

I am getting a invalid JSON even though the JSON is valid.  I am sure it is something simple.

Here is my model

```
from django.db import models


class Customer(models.Model):
    cus_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    address3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    web = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is my view

```
class CustomerListJson(BaseDatatableView):
model = Customer
columns = ['cus_name', 'address1', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone', 'email', 'web']
order_columns = ['cus_name', 'address1', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone', 'email', 'web']
max_display_length = 50

def filter_queryset(self, qs):
    search = self.request.POST.get('search[value]', None)

    if search:
        qs.filter(name__istartswith=search)

    return qs
```

Here is my url

```
url(r'^$', c.CustomerListJson.as_view(), name='customer_ajax_list'),
```

Here is my template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Customers{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="Customers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Customer
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
            <th>
                State
            </th>
            <th>
                Zip
            </th>
            <th>
                Phone
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Web
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Customers').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": {% url 'customer_ajax_list' %},
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sEmptyTable": "Loading data from server",
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "NAME", "sDefaultContent": "", "mData": "cus_name" },
                        { "sName": "ADDRESS", "sDefaultContent": "", "mData": "address1" },
                        { "sName": "CITY", "sDefaultContent": "", "mData": "city" },
                        { "sName": "STATE", "sDefaultContent": "", "mData": "state" },
                        { "sName": "ZIP", "sDefaultContent": "", "mData": "zip" },
                        { "sName": "PHONE", "sDefaultContent": "", "mData": "phone" },
                        { "sName": "EMAIL", "sDefaultContent": "", "mData": "email" },
                        { "sName": "WEB", "sDefaultContent": "", "mData": "web" },
        ]
    });
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

And here is my base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>

<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-2.1.1.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>

<title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
{% block navbar %}
<div id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/login/">Logout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/customers/">Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-2.1.1.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is my JSON

```
{"recordsTotal": 3, "recordsFiltered": 3, "result": "ok", "data": [["test1", "123 Main Street", "Chicago", "IL", "60089", "2629999999", "test@google.com", "www.google.com"], ["test2", "123 Main Street", "Chicago", "IL", "60089", "2629999999", "test@google.com", ""], ["test3", "123 Main Street", "Chicago", "IL", "60089", "2629999999", "test@google.com", ""]], "draw": 0}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is exactly wrong with your "JSON"?

Comment: Nothing that I can see.  I get a DataTables Warning Table ID=Customers - Invalid JSON Response.  See datatables.net/tn/1  My data validates fine and I can access the view to see the raw data.

Comment: https://next.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1

Comment: i do remember some issue when i was dumping dict to json for datatable. try to escape double quotes with '\' symbol

Comment: The tech-notes validates fine.  What for you mean by escaping the double quotes?  Thanks!

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I find myself with the same problem 4 years later...